# Is MySQL secured?

Tags: mysql, security

When I go to directory of MySQL `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data` all database can see as folder. When I go into those folders I can see 3 file under one table. When I see those one by one which file has extension `.MYD` I see what I inserted into that table:

> Ž  þ    KamalPerera 856345123vMale8 2008-01-08Retired 2011-05-11
>   0112543667 kamal2012@gmail.com234/23 handala rd   kadawatha kiribsthgoda
>   u  þ    Madawa Ramanayake 754123543vMale8 2011-05-22Working 
>   0112544234 0773453223 234 dabuwa rd polwattaragama ’  þ   Manuri
>   Disanayake.......................

That mean we can read all database tables and data which are inserted without any username or password.

Am I wrong? Can anyone tell me how to secure my database data?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because your User has `Administrator` status on your system. Users without administrator access should not be able to access these files. If you enable Guest User, you can login and try same thing with Guest. You should not get access to the files as guest or normal user without administrator rights.